# Jeju Island : Visa requirements

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea, jeju

I am extremely confused with visa requirements for visiting Jeju island. My plan is to visit South Korea and cover Jeju island as well.

I am an Indian citizen and I am not sure if South Korean visa will cover Jeju island trip as well as there are so many different information available on internet.

I know for sure that Indians don't need a visa to travel to Jeju island if they are travelling directly via Singapore or Shanghai i.e. you must not travel via South Korea. This leaves me very confused, so I cannot travel to South Korea and Jeju together?

Can someone please confirm on how the the visa requirement for Jeju island works?

Reference link : https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/sg-en/brd/m_2435/view.do?seq=761394&page=1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple: Jeju is a part of South Korea, so **if you have a visa for South Korea, it's valid for Jeju as well**.

There are various special programs for visiting Jeju *only*, but if you have a "full" South Korean visa, they are not relevant to you.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing confusing in the document you link to.

The Jeju part is a special visa exemption for people who need a visa to visit South Korea, like you, an Indian citizen. If they fly directly to Jeju, without passing through Incheon Airport or Busan Airport, for example, and stay only within Jeju, then they don't need a visa. But they cannot go anywhere else in Korea. Which is basically what the link you mention says.

On the other hand, if you apply for a Korean tourist visa, you can visit all of Korea, Jeju included.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151060/discussion-on-answer-by-dda-jeju-island-visa-requirements); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand after looking at that Korean embassy page:

If you have a South Korea visa, you're automatically good to visit Jeju too since it's part of Korea.

There's special visa-free entry for some nationalities flying directly to Jeju from certain countries. But since you'll be visiting all of Korea, just focus on the main SK visa.

As an Indian citizen, getting the proper SK tourist/visit visa is your best bet to safely cover both places.